# dompdf - text wrap is not working

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I have dynamic html content to create a pdf. So i am using `Dompdf`.

Here is two snap shot which will help to understand what exactly i want.

**MY HTML SHOWING LIKE THIS SNAP IN BROWSER**

[image]

**Result PDF**

[image]

Now you can see my html text and pdf text. pdf text should be the same as html.

i don't know why is this happening. and dont worry about text fonts. but in my html text, text looks in two lines but in pdf it is coming in one line. i have also used `word-wrap:break-word;` css but i think it is not supported by `Dompdf`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

$dir          = __DIR__ . '/../public';
$pdfDirectory = $dir . '/testing-pdf';
$pdfFilename  = $pdfDirectory  . '/output.pdf';

$buffer = <<<HTML
<style>@page {
    margin: 36 50;
} </style>
<div style='width:400px;height:300px;background:#C0C0C0;position:relative;'>
    <div style='width:200px;height:100px;position:absolute;top:100px; left:90px;'>
        <p style='text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:2px 0;font-size:24pt;font-family:arial; word-wrap:break-word; border:1px solid black;'>
            Abcd abc ab a
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($buffer);
$dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 400, 300), "portrait");
$dompdf->render();

file_put_contents($pdfFilename, $dompdf->output());
```

Comment: I haven't used Dompdf, but try changing your div to use max-width and see if you can force the word wrap.

Comment: tried with `max-width` but same result..

Comment: Dompdf is not a library suitable for precision PDF creation. It's a workaround, a dirty but worky, a *do it domodf because you failed to do it right* way of PDF creation. It can be fine to use (just saying), however I wonder about the expectation of yours that this should wrap the text (as there is no need actually, it fits in well into one line).

Comment: @ShailParas: That was not meant as DOMPdf bashing, however, you can not expect that a professionally designed and developed product like your browser (for HTML displaying) is at arms length as DOMPdf. That's merely what I wanted to highligh. Especially as the PDF output seems fitting to me. I do not see it as "wrong", it looks perfectly fine for that text. You perhaps want the box to be two-lines height at minimum (independent to text-wrapping)?

Comment: yes. thats what i am looking for. i want if text is showing in two lines then it should be in two lines in pdf as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.. So finally i got something which makes it work. Actually i was only looking for wrapping text but i forgot that font is also an issue. I am using `Arial` font in my `html content` thats OK with the browsers. but i just found that `dompdf` has not included `Arial` font in itself. Every time when i go to create the pdf it changed the font `Arial to Times new Roman` and `Times new Roman` is little thinner than `Arial`. Thats why it is taking the second lines text with the first line.

Comment: thanks for posting this. I'm surprised I didn't notice the font difference. A very sneaky problem in the end :)

Comment: Helvetica is included by default and fairly comparable to Arial. You can just change the font to Helvetica to fix the issue for dompdf, but it's better is to always provide a fallback, e.g. `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Comment: @BrianS - Yes you are right and i can fix the issue by changing the font. But my requirement is that i have a dynamic html content. that means i have added a tinymce editor for my user, so i need to show what font user has selected in editor. and i am also planning to install more fonts in Dompdf so that my user will not face this issue again.

Comment: I see your problem now. Definitely a good idea to install the fonts that will be available to your users.